# For loop to subset a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, subset

I have a list of dataframes:

```
df1<-data.frame("A"=1:10, "B"=c("Mark","John","Lucas","Helen","Rachel","Leyla","Tina","Fanny","Emma","Kate"),"C"=c(91:100))
df2<-data.frame("A"=1:8, "B"=c("Mark","John","Lucas","Helen","Rachel","Leyla","Tina","Fanny"),"C"=c(93:100))
df3<-data.frame("A"=1:3, "B"=c("Mark","John","Lucas"),"C"=c(98:100))
all_df<-list(df1,df2,df3)
```

And I would like to create a new list of dataframes subsetted by column, like this:

```
df1_sub<-df1[,c("B","C")]
df2_sub<-df1[,c("B","C")]
df3_sub<-df1[,c("B","C")]
all_df_sub<-list(df1_sub,df2_sub,df3_sub)
```

Finally assigning to each new dataframe its name:

```
mynames<-c("df1_sub","df2_sub","df3_sub")
names(all_df_sub)<-mynames
```

I would like to do this using `lapply` and a `for` loop, but I could not figure out how, as I get stuck somewhere in between defining the function and subsetting the list of dataframes (I am not very confident with this, I checked older similar questions without success). This is what I am trying so far:

```
all_df_sub<-lapply(all_df, function(all_df){
  for([[i]] in all_df) {
    a<-[[i]][,c("B","C")]
    } 
  all_df } )
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
all_df_sub <-lapply(all_df, function(dat){dat[2:3]})
all_df_sub <-setNames(all_df_sub, c("df1_sub","df2_sub","df3_sub"))
```